# How to Get baseURL for node.js API?

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I'm building a graphql wrapper on the backend of my node app. and i need to have the api domain be correct.

hard to google this phrase.

```
const baseURL = `http://localhost:8001/api`
```

I can run this locally but after I deploy my code it will not work since the domain be different. What are the ways to set the baseURL variable?

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of ways to achieve this.

**Method 1:**
You can use header attributes

```
var host = req.get('host');
```

But this will only return domain, in your case

```
http://localhost:8001/
```

So this may not achieve your goal.

**Method 2:**
Create .env file in root folder and then you can use dotenv package to access the baseurl.

Content in .env file

```
BASEURL = http://localhost:8001/api
```

And now in whatever file you want to access, first install the [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package using npm and than require that dotenv package using below syntax

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

After that inside your function, use this syntax to get baseurl from .env file

```
const baseURL = process.env.BASEURL;
```

Comment: i need the base url when i'm starting the graphql server, not during a request. is there a global req object?

Answer (score 0):

use this header attributes. you can identify the domain from this way.

`var host = req.get('host');
var origin = req.get('origin');`

or

`var host = req.headers.host;
var origin = req.headers.origin;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var host = req.get('host');
```

> host return base url like (http://localhost:8001/) or if use domain
>   then return domain name.
>
> i have already host just concat host with 'api'.

```
const baseURL = host + 'api';
```

Comment: this is not during a request, this is the domain of the app